# Creating a CMS agenda

Tags: php, mysql, html, content-management-system

I want to create a agenda, where you just have to login into CMS and edit.

If you enter an new event (day,month,year,hour,activity,location,street,nr,postcode,city) it should create a new part in the database.

On the other hand @ the webpage, a frame needs to be created with all the info in it automatically

[image: This is a previeuw]

You see the red frame. If ill create as an admin on the CMS control page and create a new event, a new red frame comes on top of the existing one,
if the "standard frame" is full the oldest red frame gets hided, bij clicking on some arrows (If Possible) it shows the oldest dates.

I want to know how to start, and i understand PHP but have no knowledge of it.

Thanks

Comment: "I understand PHP but have no knowledge of it" - is that some kind of koan? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand PHP but you have no knowledge?

Just start with creating a form that puts your calendar data into a database table and read it out again on some other page.
Once you have that working, I bet the rest comes easy.

Comment: That phrase caught my eye too. I *like* it.